# Existe alguma função em R que me ajude a localizar as modas de um dataset multimodal?

Tags: r, funções, modal

Algo do tipo EncontraModa(Dataset,N_Maiores_Modas)?

Estou trabalhando com os seguintes inteiros:
    c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9)

Ou seja, o exemplo é trimodal e tem uma moda maior que as outras duas.

O ideal seria talvez criar uma função que coloque todos os inteiros e ordem e subtraia-se o próximo do anterior, quando der 0 soma pra uma variavel N da moda e daí compararia essas variáveis N da moda? Estou tentando desenvolver o código pra isso mas ainda não consegui.

Comment: No seu exemplo, a moda é 9, visto que ocorre com mais frequência do que 7 e 8.

Answer (score 5):

Corrigindo a função deste site, https://www.r-bloggers.com/lang/portuguese/517 :

```
statmod <- function(x) {
  z <- table(as.vector(x))
  names(z)[z == max(z)]
}

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9)

statmod(a)

a
[1] "9"
```

Tendo 7, 8 e 9 com a mesma quantidade de repetições, ou seja, mesma moda:

```
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)

statmod(b)

b
[1] "7" "8" "9"
```

Se quiser saber a contagem de cada repetição, ordenadamente, utilize:

```
sort(table(a), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: Não deverá ser `table(as.vector(x))`? A função está a encontrar o `a` porque vai à procura fora do seu *environment* e encontra no `globalenv`.

Comment: Correto Rui! Obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito Daniel! Para conjuntos pequenos funciona muito bem, mas se eu tiver 40 mil itens, por exemplo, e precisar saber quais os 10 itens que mais repetem? Como eu subtrairia a moda do vetor para rodar o statmod de novo?

Seria isso?

    y <- x - rep(a)
    statmod(y)
    y

Ou eu alteraria o statmod para:
    statmod <- function(x,y) {
    w = 0
    for w in y {
    z <- table(as.vector(x))
    names(z)[z == max(z)]
    x - z
    }}

?